# Why bootstrap carousel and django not workig properly?

Tags: django, bootstrap-4

I am trying to provide bootstrap carousel backend with django.I have written a simple program view which will pass all images to template.But when i run the program i did't get output as expected, all images are rendered adjecent to one other. There was nothing like forward and backward button and all.And i am posting my view and template.

Thanks in advance.

Hope to here from you soon.

**View:-**

```
def TaggingView(request):
    queryset = MyImage.objects.filter(is_tagged=False)
    return render(request, "taggging.html", {'files': queryset})
```

**Template :-**

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="carouselInd" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        {% for file in files %}
        {% with forloop.counter0 as i %}
        <div class="carousel-item {% if i is 0 %}active{% endif %}">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{ file.image.url }}" alt="" style="height: 30rem;">
        </div>
        {% endwith %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**output:-**

[image: Output which i am getting..]

Comment: All your images are wrapped in a `<div>` with `active` as one of the `class`es...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem sorry i did't understand.. please

Comment: all images are wrapped in a `<div class="carousel-item active">` so with `active`...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem So what i need to do, i don't have enough knowledge of bootstrap and all, i am fresher backend developer, so please....

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i tried to remove <div class="carousel-item active">, it did't work...how to unwrap all images

Comment: @Rvector i am getting same output as before, no change

Comment: @Rvector i have updated the template and also added the output which i am getting.Please have a look Thanks for you help and support

Comment: @Rvector have a look on template code i have add the whole template code

Comment: You are using the version 3.4, but the code i wrote use `v4.6` : it is [Bootstrap v4.6](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/getting-started/introduction/). May be it's the difference. Also try to use `CDN` as most a possible. **Use the v4.6 and let us know**

Comment: @Rvector it working thanks thanks a lot, but its forward and backward button are not workig

Comment: The `id` here `carouselInd` attribute of the main carousel `div` block must be the same as those of the `href` attribute for the `a` (previous and next link). Then replace `#carouselExampleControls` by `#carouselInd`.

Comment: If it work, then mark the answer that it solve your question ;-)

Comment: i have! @Rvector

Comment: yeah Good Luck !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Django work fine with Bootstrap carousel, you need to be aware with the active class like this :**

```
<div id="carouselInd" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        {% for file in files %}
        {% with forloop.counter0 as i %}
        <div class="carousel-item {% if i is 0 %}active{% endif %}">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{ file.image.url }}" alt=" 
            {{ file.name }}" style="height: 30rem;">
        </div>
        {% endwith %}
        {% endfor %}

    </div>
</div>
```

**NB :** The `alt` attribute is dynamic, you can use a static value if you want. And give a `height` to the image can help to contain the image too.

Comment: is it is not working..Sorry, i am getting save output as before

Comment: Show me an image please

Comment: i have updated the template and also added the output which i am getting.Please have a look Thanks for you help and support

Comment: Do you have bootstrap loaded  well ? Where are you load the bootstrap library ?

Comment: have a look on template code i have add the whole template code